# Can we write each integer $n>8$ as $k+m$ with $0<k<m$ such that $\varphi(k)\varphi(m)$ is a square?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Here I ask a somewhat curious question on Euler's totient function $\varphi$.

QUESTION: Can we write each integer $n>8$ as $k+m$ with $k$ and $m$ distinct positive integers such that $\varphi(k)\varphi(m)$ is a square?

Based on my computation, in 2014 I conjectured that the answer is yes. For example,
\begin{align*}17&=5+12\ \ \text{with}\ \varphi(5)\varphi(12)=4\times4=4^2,
\\24&=4+20\ \ \text{with}\ \ \varphi(4)\varphi(20)=2\times8=4^2,
\\56&=8+48\ \ \text{with}\ \ \varphi(8)\varphi(48)=4\times16=8^2.
\end{align*}
Though the graph available from http://oeis.org/A236998/graph reflecting the growth of
$$\text{A236998}(n)=\left|\left\{0<k<\frac n2:\ \varphi(k)\varphi(n-k)\ \text{is a square}\right\}\right|$$
supports my conjecture, I feel rather puzzled since I do not see why the conjecture is reasonable.

By the way, in 2013 I conjectured that any integer $n>5$ can be written as the sum of two positive integers $k$ and $m$ such that $(\varphi(k)+\varphi(m))/2$ is prime (cf. http://oeis.org/A233918). This is still open.

Any comments are welcome!